# Класс. Наследование. Конструктор parent::__construct()

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Вот код. По идее, должно вывести 29,232. Но получается 0. Подскажите.
    введите код здесь

```
    //базовый класс
class Counter {
 protected $show0;
 protected $show1;
 function __construct($arg0, $arg1) {
  $this->show0 = $arg0;
  $this->show1 = $arg1;
 }
 function Res() {
  return ($this->show1 - $this->show0);
 }
}

//производный класс
class Price extends Counter {
 private $price;
 function __construct($arg) {
  $this->price = $arg;
  //конструктор базового класса
  parent::__construct($baseArg0, $baseArg1);
 }
 function Sum() {
  return ( $this->Res() * $this->price );
 }
}

$P = new Price(0.2436, 0, 120);
echo $P->Sum(), '<br />';
```

Comment: форматируйте код, кнопочка **{}**

Comment: что такое по вашему $baseArg0 ?

Answer (score 2):

Надо  взять аргументы функции, вместо того, чтобы undefined использовать:

```
class Counter {
 protected $show0;
 protected $show1;
 function __construct($arg0, $arg1) {
  $this->show0 = $arg0;
  $this->show1 = $arg1;
 }
 function Res() {
  return ($this->show1 - $this->show0);
 }
}

//производный класс
class Price extends Counter {
 private $price;
 function __construct($arg) {
     $args=func_get_args(); //<- тут
  $this->price = $arg;
  //конструктор базового класса
  parent::__construct($args[1],$args[2]); // <-тут
 }
 function Sum() {
  return ( $this->Res() * $this->price );
 }
}

$P = new Price(0.2436, 0, 120);
echo $P->Sum(), '<br />';
```

[демо](http://ideone.com/Fid2SU)

правда, это неправильно так использовать наследование,

Comment: Я так и сделал, по прежненму в ответе 0

Comment: Уважаемый eicto, все получилось! Спасибо Вам! Я только изучаю PHP, разбираю тему класс, наследование. В языке С# это все делается. Вот почти такой же пример.

Comment: @eicto, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

я говорю, что так делать не правильно, а не то что не получится. 

(в C# интерпретатор сам угадывает что вы имели ввиду когда использовали неопределенную переменную ?) /sarkazm **всё, перехожу на c#**

Comment: А как же правильно? Два класса, у обоих конструкторы, принимающие параметры. Как же тогда?

Comment: Уважаемый @eicto, Вы просмотрите такую же тему. Там я показал код на C#. Правда там компилятор, а не интерпретатор.

Comment: @shloma неправильно наследовать Price от Counter, по крайней мере в таком виде.